# ngModel.$parsers not working in directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to dynamically add directives to form elements (input,select,textarea...)

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form form-validator>
    <input type="text" ng-model="model1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="model2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="model3">
    <textarea ng-model="model4"></textarea>
    <select>
       <option ng-model="model5" value="1">Name</option>
    </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Directives

```
var app=angular.module('app',[])
.controller('ctrl',function($scope){

})
.directive('formValidator',function($compile){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            //is it possible to do this with one line of code?
            elem.find('input').attr('validate-field','');
            elem.find('select').attr('validate-field','');
            elem.find('textarea').attr('validate-field','');
            $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
})
.directive('validateField',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require:['^ngModel'],
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrls){
            var valid = false;
            var ngModel = ctrls[0];
            alert('before validation');
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value){ 
               alert('validating');
               valid = validator(value);
               ngModel.$setValidity('required', valid, ctrls);
               return valid ? value : undefined;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The code above was able to add `validate-field` attribute to form elements:

`<input type="text" ng-model="model1" validate-field>`

The problem is `ngModel.$parsers.unshift` is not being called, `alert('before validation');` is called but `alert('validating');` is not being called.

What am I missing?

Comment: you should use `require: ['ngModel']` inside your `validateField` directive to make it working.. so that the `ngModelController` will be available to use.

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar still doesn't work when `require:['^ngModel'],` is added

Comment: please can you show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: You don't need to add `^` sign as `ng-model` directive on same element.. it should be `require:['ngModel']`

Comment: I am afraid it still doesn't work with `require:['ngModel']`

Comment: could you add plunkr/fiddle for the same?

Comment: here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/gzbBABT1vPDFkmJv9HJG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently what happening is you `formValidator` directive link function is evaluating after all child `validateField` directive gets compiled. Because `link: function(){ .. }` function is considered as same as postLink function, which gets called after all children `scope` linking ready. Same thing is happening in your case.

So I'd say say that do call your link function to ensure that it will add `validate-fields` before directive gets compile. For that you need to use `preLink` function.

```
.directive('formValidator', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: {
        pre: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          elem.find('input').attr('validate-field', '');
          elem.find('select').attr('validate-field', '');
          elem.find('textarea').attr('validate-field', '');
          $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
        }
      }
    }
})
```

[**Plunkr Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VhvxgZ07F9o8Lg1g7BWr?p=preview)

---

More better version would be compile parent directive only once

```
  .directive('formValidator', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function(elem, attrs) {
        elem.find('input').attr('validate-field', '');
        elem.find('select').attr('validate-field', '');
        elem.find('textarea').attr('validate-field', '');
        //removed to avoid infinite directive compile
        elem.removeAttr('form-validator');
        var linkFn = $compile(elem);
        return function(scope, element, attr) {
          linkFn(scope);
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

[**Check here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DIpKZPjOAc4QeZxZmRfh?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you want use `$formatters`.

Example on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/AEyHOmQ78DRmGSNHxjIi?p=preview).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@2.0.0" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Angular Directive</h1>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
      <form form-validator="">
        <input type="text" ng-model="model1" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="model2" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="model3" />
        <textarea ng-model="model4"></textarea>
        <select ng-model="model5">
          <option value="1">Name</option>
        </select>
        <button ng-click="model1='A'"> set model 1 value A</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      
    var app=angular.module('app',[])
    .controller('ctrl',function($scope){

     })
     .directive('formValidator',function($compile){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        priority:10000,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            //is it possible to do this with one line of code?
            elem.find('input').attr('validate-field','');
            elem.find('select').attr('validate-field','');
            elem.find('textarea').attr('validate-field','');
            $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
   })
   .directive('validateField',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require:'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
            var valid = false;
            console.log('before validation',ngModel);
            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (value){ 
               console.log('validating');
               //valid = validator(value);
               ngModel.$setValidity('required', valid, ngModel);
               return valid ? value : undefined;
            });
             ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value){ 
               console.log('$parsers');
               valid = true;
               ngModel.$setValidity('required', valid, ngModel);
               return valid ? value : undefined;
            });
        }
    }
  });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you for responding +1 for you