# AngularJS $parser not being called when dynamically adding the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So what i'm trying to achieve is to be able to add a directive that contains a parser through another directive.
When directly adding the parser directive on an html element it works completely fine. the parser directive i currently use:

```
.directive('parseTest', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: ['ngModel'],
            link: {
                post: function (scope, element, attributes, ctrls) {
                    var controller = ctrls[0];
                    controller.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                        var result = value.toLowerCase();
                        controller.$setViewValue(value);
                        controller.$render();

                        return result;
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Now when i add this directive through another directive the parser never gets called weirdly enough. The directive that generated the parsetest directive:

```
.directive('generateTest', ['$compile',
    function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: function (elem, attrs) {

                elem.attr('parse-test', '');
                elem.removeAttr('generate-test');
                var linkFn = $compile(elem);
                return function (scope, element, attr) {
                    linkFn(scope);
                }
            }               
        }
    }
])
```

The following works fine:

```
<input class="form-control col-sm-6" ng-model="model.parsetest" parse-test/>
```

The following doesn't work (While the generated result html is the same)

```
<input class="form-control col-sm-6" ng-model="model.generateTest" generate-test />
```

**So my question is how can i get the parser working when it is in a dynamicly added directive?**

Note, i already tried the solution to a similar issue from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35981578/ngmodel-parsers-not-working-in-directive), but that doesn't work for me.

EDIT: [Here is a plnkr that demonstrates the issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/mn13mR7JxdBlUWY3o8pI?p=preview), both fields have the parse-test directive applied to it that should make the value in the model lowercase, but it only works for the one that is not dynamically added as shown in the console logs.

Comment: If i am not wrong you haven't written any logic under `linkFn` of `generateTest`. Try to add some logic and then try.

Comment: @dev_khan What kind of logic are you refering to. As of right now that part does it job, it compiles the element then binds the scope to that element (Atleast that is what i assumed it does). So i'm not seeing what i should add to that to fix the parser problem :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the solution, so for anyone that stumbles on the same issue here it is.

The 2 small changes have to made to the directive that generates the directive that contains a parser or formatter.
First of set the priority of the directive to a number higher or equal as 1. Secondly put terminal on true. Those 2 settings seem to resolve the issue. 
The problem probably lies in that the default execution of nested directives makes it so that the parser and formatters get inserted slightly to late which is why we need to make sure the directive gets generated first thing before anything else.

This is just an assumption of why it works tho, if anyone else has an explanation it would be great :)

As for the code, the directive that generates another directive should look something like:

```
directive('generateTest', ['$compile',
    function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            terminal: true,
            priority: 1,
            compile: function (elem, attrs) {

                attrs.$set('parseTest', '');
                attrs.$set('generateTest', undefined);
                var linkFn = $compile(elem);
                return function (scope, element, attr) {
                    linkFn(scope);
                }
            }               
        }
    }
])
```